# Use different math font for different subplots in the same figure?

Tags: matplotlib, axes, font-style

I am trying to use different [math font sets](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#fonts) for two axes in the same figure, with no success. I have searched this issue using google and I have read the matplotlib's official guide on how to use the math font. But I can not find ways to achieve this effect. My complete code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm' # use font "cm" for first axes
ax1.text(0.3, 0.5, r"$xyz$", fontsize=50)
ax1.set_title('before')
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stixsans' # use font "stixsans" for second axes
ax2.text(0.3, 0.5, r"$xyz$", fontsize=50)
ax2.set_title('after')
ax2.axis('off'）
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

The resulting figure shows that both the axes use the "stixsans" font, see [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxOc6.png).

It seems that `mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stixsans'` in the later part has overruled the previous setting `mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'`.  Any idea how to prevent this from happening and use "cm" and "stixsans" font for the two axes respectively?

Comment: Actually I doubt that this is possible. Even the [style context](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#temporary-styling) manager seems to ignore the `mathtext.fontset` parameter.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7107

Comment: @tom yeah, closely related. So it can not be achieved in the near term.